# How to use function parameter in sql query?

Tags: objective-c, parameters, char

I am trying to create a sql query in Objective-C. But in where clause I want to use a parameter that comes from a function. I couldn't append it to query.
The query must be char type. My parameter is integer. I tried to convert them into string to use `stringFormat:` and `appendString:` options but it didn't work.
I am trying to concentrate two chars, but I couldn't.

Here is the code;

```
(NSMutableArray*)getSomething:(NSInteger)some_id
{
    NSMutableArray *something = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    // const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM t_something WHERE some_id = ";
```

I want to use some_id parameter in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this example code

```
NSString *stmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM person where word like '%@%% order by name asc",name];


    const char *sql=(const char *) [stmt UTF8String];
```